# Is there an appropriate Stack Exchange site to ask for recommendations on good software technical interview problems?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm doing technical interviews for the first time, and need advice on good interview questions, or resources.

Is https://stackoverflow.com the correct site for this? Is there not one?

Comment: The Workplace https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ has a tag for recruitment but I am not a member of that site so I cannot say whether your question would be on-topic there. If you do not get a better answer it might be best to ask on their meta first.

Comment: I'm afraid we closed the sites for bad software technical interview problems...

Comment: ...can your colleagues not help you out with this one?  You're not interviewing by yourself, are you?

Comment: @Makoto, I Am the only software person currently in my organization. We're looking to double to TWO software people... so yes, I'm doing this by myself...

Comment: The SO blog did run a few articles on technical interviewing: https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/02/18/the-stack-overflow-interviewing-process/ ; https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/10/24/stack-overflow-92-podcast-the-guerilla-guide-to-interviewing/ ; https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/04/06/how-to-run-successful-developer-interviews-remotely/

Answer (score -1):

[The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/)

Many of the questions there are related to the software industry, so it seems a good bet to ask there.

However, simply asking for a list of interview questions probably won't be accepted there - you're better off looking these up yourself.

You can ask for advice on how to approach certain questions though, assuming the same questions haven't been discussed before.

If you have the rep, feel free to ask for advice in the main chatroom there.

Comment: No I think the OP is exactly looking for guidance on what kinds of technical questions to ask in an interview which is a Big Yikes™ from me.